# Sailpoint Creation Rule

Tags: sailpoint

This the bean shell code to set Aaron nichols as Application owner and to set the password

if (identity ==null) {

```
identity.setPassword("xyzzy");
```

Identity AppOwner = context.getObjectByName(Identity.class, "Aaron.Nichols");

```
application.setOwner(AppOwner);
```

}

Exception occuring:-
1)Exception during aggregation of 1a. Reason: BeanShell script error: bsh.ParseException: Parse error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: < BSF info: Custom Rule Ag at line: 0 column: columnNo
2)Exception during aggregation of 1a. Reason: BeanShell script error: bsh.ParseException: Parse error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: < BSF info: Custom Rule Ag at line: 0 column: columnNo
Exception during aggregation of 1b. Reason: BeanShell script error: bsh.ParseException: Parse error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: < BSF info: Custom Rule Ag at line: 0 column: columnNo
Exception during aggregation of 1c. Reason: BeanShell script error: bsh.ParseException: Parse error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: < BSF info: Custom Rule Ag at line: 0 column: columnNo
Exception during aggregation of 1a2ax. Reason: BeanShell script error: bsh.ParseException: Parse error at line 1, column 1. Encountered: < BSF info: Custom Rule Ag at line: 0 column: columnNo

TroubleShot:-Checked my xml it works